# SQL Server query stuck, but running with no wait

Tags: sql-server-2012, database-performance

I have an SSIS package that is running an execute SQL task, that calls a proc. The query I am dealing with is nasty, developed by vendor, which is actually nested a couple proc's deep. To add to that it uses temp tables from the parent proc as well as two nested `NOT IN` subqueries.

Currently not able to rewrite, but the question is more on identifying what could be causing the issue. The query, like mentioned, is poor but typically runs quickly, however it is stuck now. Looking at the query from `dm_exec_requests` I can see that it is in the `RUNNING` state and no waits. I see no activity from I/O, not any real CPU activity.

Is there a way to identify what is actually going on with the query?

Answer (score 5):

Sounds like there may be a deadlock issue. To see a list of blocked sys processes (deadlocks) you can run the following:

select * from sysprocesses where blocked > 0

If there are no deadlocks, it could be a performance issue and I would run a SQL trace through  profiler in SQL Server management studio. In that case, you can right click and execute the stored proc, passing in the same params as would be passed in from the SSIS package. Then examine the profiler and see where the bottlenecks are.

Regards, Rob

Comment: Thats the odd thing. No deadlocks, zero other processes running. No blocking at all. I can run the process again and it will run fine. Execution plan is not bad and it is doing an insert. I just have no idea what could cause it to just stall. This happens about once per 2 months, but no true regularity.

Comment: @DustinLaine did you ever figure this out? We have a similar issue.

Comment: Sorry I do not recall that as it was 5 years ago. However I would take the suggestion of this answer.